# li:hover issue in Explorer

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm having an issue with IE not rendering a :hover effect.  Here is my CSS

```css
#navlist li:hover {
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffa23e, #e1841f);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.00, #ffa23e), color-stop(1.0, #e1841f));
}
```

I have found something online that says IE ignores :hover except on anchor tags.  In any case, does anyone know the right workaround for this?

Also, I am using the HTML5 doctype - would that cause problems here?

Comment: works fine in IE9, what version are you using and what is the result? e.g. nothing, only certain properties are affected, etc.

Comment: Semantically speaking you should be hovering on an A-tag anyway.

Comment: It's only IE6 and below that don't support the `:hover` selector on all elements (only links).

Comment: I have version 9 too, is there something wrong in my webkit syntax?

Comment: Besides animuson's note about IE6 and `hover`, IE8 and under do not support `border-radius` and no IE will support your two `background-image` properties, so if those are what are not working, that may be your answer.

Comment: `webkit` targets Safari and Chrome, not IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-moz-linear-gradient` and `-webkit-gradient` do not work in IE. At all. [CSS gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to the rescue.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy, this I did not know :)

Comment: Wanted to add another URL for a handy background gradient using SVG: [ie.microsoft.com](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/svggradientbackgroundmaker/default.html)

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that you have used the doctype right and have no other errors in your code I assume you use IE6. Every higher version supports hover on all elements.
There are two possibilities to get a hover working on IE6.

1. javascript for onmouseover and onmouseout.
2. using the old hover.htc, if you still find it somewhere to download and integrate a behavior.

```css
body { behavior:url("csshover.htc"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

See IE comments in relation to your code.

```css
#navlist li:hover { /*hover not for IE6 or under on li elements*/
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px; /*only works in IE9+ */
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffa23e, #e1841f); /*not IE*/
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.00, #ffa23e), color-stop(1.0, #e1841f)); /*not IE*/
}
```